# Discord.py Random Presence Selection returns no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a random task loop for my discord bot. I can already have the status change with an ordered list of outcomes but I'm trying to have it display random outcomes with appropriate presences (watching, playing, etc.). At the moment the task does change, however it fails to show (or make) the random selection when tested, leaving one of the two outcomes being blank (i.e. there is no outcome involving a presence and 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs', only a blank line that changes to the set outcome I've made manually). This code is written in Python 3.6.X, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
def rand_task():
    '''random condition picker'''
    tasks = [
        'playing', 'streaming', 'listening', 'watching'
        ]
    return choice(tasks)

async def status_task():  
    '''random task looper'''
    while True:
        _play = ['foo'
            ]

        _stream = ['bar'
            ]

        _watch = ['spam'
            ]

        _listen = ['eggs'
            ]

        status = rand_task()
        if status == 'playing':
            _name = choice(_play)
            _type = '0'
            _url = None

        elif status == 'streaming':
            _name = choice(_stream)
            _type = '1'
            _url = None

        elif status == 'listening':
            _name = choice(_watch)
            _type = '2'
            _url = None

        elif status == 'watching':
            _name = choice(_listen)
            _type = '3'
            _url = None

        await bot.change_presence(game=d.Game(name='for -help', type=3))
        await sleep(2)
        await bot.change_presence(game=d.Game(name=_name, url=_url, type=_type))
        await sleep(1)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
```

Comment: Which version of the `discord.py` library are you using?  If you aren't already, you might want to consider switching to the rewrite branch, the API around presence is more mature there: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence

Comment: I've been considering to switching to the rewrite branch recently, might do that in the near future, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_type` variables are strings, they should be integers.

```
    if status == 'playing':
        _name = choice(_play)
        _type = 0
        _url = None
    # etc
```